# Can't install Homebrew on OSX

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to install Homebrew on OSX El Capitan.  All latest OSX and Xcode updates have been installed.

I am using this command in terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And I get this response:

```
curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Elsewhere I read that you can run this command to fix:

```
sudo port install curl +ssl
```

But this gave me:

```
sudo: port: command not found
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you install curl from any source? What output do you get if you type `which curl` in the terminal? The port command is from macports which is a tool similar to homebrew. I would not recommend using both at the same time.

Comment: For which curl I get /usr/local/bin/curl.  I don't believe I have installed another curl (i don't even know what curl is).

Comment: Okay, it seems that "something" has installed a curl in your local folder. Try using the command you used before but instead of `curl` use `/usr/bin/curl` to use the system version.

Comment: That worked!  How odd - do you know how I can remove this other curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am summarising my answer from comments.

In your case it seems that something has installed a version of curl without into https support into your local folder. Maybe you tried to compile it yourself (the standard `.configure && make && make install` procedure installs programs into `/usr/local` for example.

You can force the command to use system curl by replacing `curl` by `/usr/bin/curl` in it, thus use:

```
ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

When you have Homebrew successfully installed you can re-install the curl in your local folder by using:

```
brew install curl
```

There might be some additional steps as you have to overwrite files that are already there. You might need to use the `--overwrite` option.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I found this issue to be a supreme head#### as I needed cURL SSL to install brew, then apparently some people's advice was to use brew to install cURL with SSL! Your solution a godsend! I just need to do clean reinstall of gradle for Android SDK